# How to create my own Lottie animations in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, android-animation, lottie

I want to create my own Lottie animations but don't know from where to start.
Please guide me for this.
I am creating animated gifts and entries for my live streaming app and for that I need to create my own Lottie animations

Comment: Do you mean that want to implement (show) lottie animation in your app?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create them in Adobe AfterEffects. This youtube link is a good start [Create Lottie Animation in AfterEffects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q78c_NPWbII)